# Positioning errors contact form with PHP validation

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I am trying to create a contact form with PHP validation where the error messages can be positioned above, under or in the form field. Now all the messages ar shown together at the left top. I tried to make 3 classes:
error_name, error-email and error_message and I hoped that this would make it possible to position these message, where I want to, but this didn't help. Could someone tell me where I am going wrong, or how I could achieve this.

Thanks in advance

The contact form looks like:

```
<?php require_once 'validation.php'; ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Forms</title>
<style type="text/css">
 .errorlist, .error input{
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    background: #fdd;
 }
 form.cmxform fieldset {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
 form.cmxform legend {
    padding: 0 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
 }
 form.cmxform label {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1.8;
    vertical-align: top;
 }
 form.cmxform em {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #f00;
 }
 form.cmxform label {
    width: 100%; /* Width of labels */
 }
 input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
 }
 .contact {
    width: 100%;
 }
 .formfield {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  } 
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="contact">
   <div class="formfield">
   <form action="index.php" method="post" class="cmxform">

   <p>Please complete the form below. Mandatory fields marked<em>*</em></p>

  <fieldset>
    <div class="fieldset">
      <legend>Delivery Details</legend>

          <input id="name" class="error_name" name="name" placeholder="What is your name?" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['name']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']) : '' ?>" 
          />
          <div class="error_name"></div>
          <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="email" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']) : '' ?>" />
          <div class="error_email"></div>

          <input id="message" class="error_message" name="message" placeholder="message" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['message']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']) : '' ?>" />

          <input type="submit" value="Verstuur" />
       </div>
     </fieldset>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The validation.php looks like:

```
<?php
 //  We gaan de errors in een array bijhouden
$aErrors = array();

   if ('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {

   if ( !isset($_POST['name']) or !preg_match( '~^[\w ]{3,}$~',     $_POST['name'] ) ) {
   $aErrors['name'] = 'Please fill in your name';
}

if ( !isset($_POST['email']) or !preg_match( '~^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9_.\-]*@([a-z0-9]+\.)*[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,6})$~i', $_POST['email'] ) ) {
$aErrors['email'] = 'Please fill in your e-mail address';
}

if ( !isset($_POST['message']) or !preg_match( '~^[\w\d ]{28,}$~',  $_POST['message'] ) ) {
$aErrors['message'] = 'What would you like to share?';
}

if ( count($aErrors) == 0 ) {

header('Location: http://www.phpfreakz.nl/someotherpage.php');
exit();
}
}

 if ( isset($aErrors['name']) and count($aErrors['name']) > 0 ) {
   print '<div class="error_name">';
   if ( $aErrors['name'] ) {
   print '<div>' . $aErrors['name'] . '</div>';
   }
   print '</div>';
   }

 if ( isset($aErrors['email']) and count($aErrors['email']) > 0 ) {
   print '<div class="error_email">';
   if ( $aErrors['email'] ) {
   print '<div>' . $aErrors['email'] . '</div>';
   }
   print '</div>';
   }

 if ( isset($aErrors['message']) and count($aErrors['message']) > 0 ) {
   print '<div class="error_message">';
   if ( $aErrors['message'] ) {
   print '<div>' . $aErrors['message'] . '</div>';
   }
   print '</div>';
   }
?>
```

Comment: Do validations using JavaScript. I wouldn't recommend to sent server requests just to see if the form is filled correctly - Client side should do it :)

Comment: I thought ( looking at the internet) that server side Validation is the best way, so validation can't be passed when Java is turned of at client side.

Comment: Any webpage is based on HTML,CSS and JavaScript as frontend. Javascript is never turned off because if it was, you wouldn't see 99% of the websites.

Comment: @Yair.R

Yes, but anyone with bad intent can still turn off javascript. If the site is not visible without javascript( which is certainly not always the case), he/she could still mess up the system by simple sending the POST data to the server, or by editting some javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the errors immediately, keep them in your array and print them later. Add empty strings first in validation.php to make sure you do not print a value which doesnt exist. Example for name error:

```
<?php
 //  We gaan de errors in een array bijhouden
$aErrors = array();
$aErrors['name'] = '';


 //..Rest of your validation script here
```

Then in the contact form, change this:

```
<div class="error_name"></div>
```

To this:

```
<div class="error_name"><?php print $aErrors['name'];?></div>
```

Ps: I do not have enough points to comment, but you are right, never rely on client side evaluation of the form since every user can disable javascript. The best way is to do both, but if you do not want to do that always keep the php validation.